# Create Table Query for Redshift for the given datatypes

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

for below data set can anyone provide me the redshift query please

```
0     object
1     object
2    float64
3    float64
4     object
5     object
dtype: object
```

the query that i have tried is

```
CREATE TABLE `promos_zivame` (SKU varchar(max), Category_id varchar(max) NOT NULL, price int(max), specialPrice int(max), sizes varchar(MAX), offer varchar(MAX), Date_Time TIMESTAMP(max))
```

The error im getting this error

Error encountered: Load into table 'promos_zivame' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.

The data present in those objects are

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMQKV.png)

Comment: MySql?? Sql-Server?? AWS- RedShift??? Why do you tag everything?

Comment: sorry my bad its only for AWS-Redshift im really sorry

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not images. (And I can't read that tiny image text anyway.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
CREATE TABLE `promos_zivame` (
SKU varchar(max), 
Category_id varchar(max) NOT NULL, 
price INTEGER, 
specialPrice INTEGER, 
sizes varchar(MAX), 
offer varchar(MAX), 
Date_Time TIMESTAMP)
```

`INT` and `TIMESTAMP` doesn't take `MAX` arguments.

Comment: Ok. Please query the `stl_load_errors` and post the result. Let us see what is the exact error. @GauthamArcot

Comment: it says data types are not matched,  @arunpalanisamy

Comment: the data is above

Comment: Invalid digit, Value 'p', Pos 0, Type: Integer

Comment: @GauthamArcot, Then you are trying to insert `STRING` value to the `INTEGER` column. Is the column name mentioned in the error? Otherwise,Can you create the table with `VARCHAR(MAX)` for `price` and `specialprice` columns and check if that works?

Comment: hey thanks i have converted the result into the string into a csv then used varchar(max) it worked -@Arun